# how can we deploy xap file directly to windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i have an app which is ready to test on device but neither i have unlock device nor i want to install zune software on system.

I just want to send xap file to a device & then want to test on it.

is it possible ?

Look guys i am new in Windows phone development.
i don't have any developer account & also any unlocked device.
i just made a new app & now i want to test it on a device..
please tell me the process how to do that ?

Comment: [How to deploy XAP file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565(v=vs.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device has to be developer unlocked or the .xap file has to be downloaded from the store.
You can submit the app to the store as a private beta - only the users which emails you specify will be able to install the app. The app doesn't go through certification and is ready for download in a couple of hours.

Comment: is it possible that i directly send xap file to windows phone device & then test it because i don't have device to test right now & one of my friend have Windows phone but the device is not unlocked...

Comment: @user3349583 no. if that was possible, the option of unlocking the device would be useless..

Comment: @user3349583 It is like lisp has said - if you don't have a phone, you will have to find a beta tester. For that purpose you have to have a developer account. The friend's phone then doesn't need to be unlocked. Thought developing this way can be hard. [More information about beta testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: @user3349583 No, the device **must** be unlocked.

Comment: @ToniPetrina AFAIK the beta tester's phone doesn't need to be unlocked.

Comment: But you have to have an account for beta testing, isn't that correct?

Comment: if i have a developer account & i give my credentials to a tester then  it would be possible to send xap directly to windows phone which is unlocked ?

Comment: @user3349583 If you have an unlocked phone, then you can connect it via USB and deploy App directly. If you have developer account then you can publish beta version of the App and add your friends e-mail to beta testers list, then he will be able to download the App from the link you will receive from Windows Store.

Comment: for beta testing, it is necessary to unlock device or just install app from beta account?

Comment: @user3349583 the device deosn't have to be unlocked. During submision you specify the microsoft-account-email that beta-tester's device is connected to and that's all - he can download and install.